# Best way to master MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to the world of MS Access. I have already worked on it for a few days now. What I have done mostly is to look for solutions on web, do some relevant research and get going. 
I was wondering if anyone could share: 
What is the best way of mastering MS Access? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jay, Stack Overflow works best for questions about a specific programming problem you're facing, usually with code examples, what you've tried to solve the problem, and what you expect the output to be. Suggestions really don't fit the Q&A model as it's difficult to tell what is the best answer. The best thing you can do is continue to look at tutorials like you're doing. It sounds like you're on the right track! Good luck! :)

Comment: Sorry for posting the question here.

Comment: No worries, my suggestion is to try the examples then come back and edit this post with something specific. There is an automatic question ban that can be triggered if you ask too many of these, so it might be worth trying to improve it later on when you have something more concrete. Good luck in your Access studies!! And Welcome to Stack Overflow!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not the method du jour in a web-based world, my recommendation is NOT to look on the web to try to learn a piece of software because you'll be getting a scattergun effect. You'll be getting a bit here, a bit there, some good techniques, some really poor techniques (and at your skill level no way to know the difference) but more importantly... you won't be getting the required CONTEXT to help you understand the various parts of the product and how they connect into a whole.

I would therefore get a decent introductory level textbook which will normally lead you through understanding basic concepts, building on each one so that you grow into the product as you go. I don't do much with Access any more so I can't recommend a specific book but have found that O'Reilly ( http://search.oreilly.com/?q=Access&x=0&y=0 ) has a range of good books in both paper and digital formats.

If you do want to learn from the web, I'd recommend a structured training program such as the ones offered by Lynda.com or Total Training. I've subscribed to both at various times and although I'm currently a Lynda member, TT's courses are usually quite good as well. There are probably some others but I can't give any first hand recommendations on those.

Good luck with your studies.